# Mapping a collection to subdocuments - Maximum serialization depth exceeded (does the object being serialized have a circular reference?)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've got the following model:

```
public class Competitor
{
    public virtual int CompetitorId { get; set; }
    public virtual string TeamName { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<CompetitorBest> CompetitorBests { get; set; }
}


public class CompetitorBest
{
    public virtual int ResultId { get; set; }
    public virtual string BestTypeName { get; set; }
    public virtual string IndoorOutdoor { get; set; }
    public virtual int Season { get; set; }
    public virtual string DisciplineName { get; set; }
    public virtual string ResultValue { get; set; }
}
```

When trying to save it to my MongoDB instance, I get the following error:

> Maximum serialization depth exceeded (does the object being serialized have a circular reference?).

I'm using automapping (ie- not set any class mapping)

I can't see what could be wrong?
There's no circular reference?

Comment: How does the CompetitorBests collection looks like?

Comment: It's a collection of CompetitorBest - the class is there?

Comment: What type of collection is it? Does it have a reference to the parent Competitor object?

Comment: it's right there... i supplied the code. It's an IEnumerable<CompetitorBest> - in my Competitor class

Comment: I mean implementation, not an IEnumerable interface. Instance of what type is there at the moment of serialization?

Comment: I'm really not sure I understand your question...
This error occurs when saving in to mongo. The model is hydrated from nHibernate prior to this.

Comment: It's impossible to create an instance of an interface in C#. nHibernate may create (it's my supposition) a container class for it. If it contains a reference to the parent object, there will be a circular reference.

Comment: I know it's impossible to create an instance. Do you have a suggestion of what I should do to prevent this? Perhaps create a class map for mongo and ignore something?

Comment: In answer to your question, it's an implementation of NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag - so might be along the right track now....

Comment: This helped me solve a very similar problem. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
I'm submitting this as an answer, mainly because it *works* - ie, allows me to save the document as required.

As @chebum correctly pointed out, the problem is actually with the fact I'm pulling the entities using that model using nHibernate first.
This means that my **IEnumerable< CompetitorBest >** on my Competitor object, is actually of **type NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag**

As correctly pointed out by @chebum in the comments, this will have a reference to the original object, therefore creating a circular reference.

Rather than create a mongodb class map (which is what I should probably do.. feel free to answer) this is what I did to get things working for now.

Changed my Competitor class to this:

```
public class Competitor
{
    private IList<CompetitorBest> _competitorBests;

    //other properties

    public virtual IEnumerable<CompetitorBest> CompetitorBests
    {
        get { return _competitorBests.ToArray(); }
        set { }
    }
}
```

Then in my nHibernate Class Map:

```
HasMany(x => x.CompetitorBests)
    .Not.LazyLoad()
    .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
    .Inverse()
    .AsBag()
    .KeyColumn("competitorId");
```

Again, I'm sure there's a better way of doing it (perhaps with a mongodb class mapping??)
But i've added this as it works for me... for now.